# Trying to boot Debian on external HDD

Tags: debian, boot, grub, macintosh, refind

I’ve installed Debian using a bootable usb 3 times now trying to make this work. The issue is that instead of booting into Debian the computer boots into a grub command line. When I use the command `boot` it says to load a kernel first. I have no idea how to do that. After 2 days of no luck with grub, I installed `rEFInd`, which I hoped would give me the option to boot into Debian. Not the case. There are 2 options that look promising, one with the Debian icon, and one with the Linux icon, but they both point towards a file called `grubx64.efi` which boots into the command line. I’m extremely confused because every time the installer said it was successful but it also boots into grub still. That didn’t happen in any tutorials I watched. I’ve looked for any and every fix online and tried at least 20 thing but they didn’t help. I feel like I missed a step between the finished installation and when I expected Debian to boot but there isn’t a step between those in anything I’ve seen.

rEFInd:
[image]
[image]